# Prior to use or prior to using

Tags: word-usage

I am just confused about using "prior to". As I understand, after the word "to", we always use a verb with "ing". However, I read that we can use "prior to " with a verb without "ing".

For example, which of the following sentences is correct and why?

> 1- Prior to introduce the method of ....
>
> 2- Prior to introducing the method of ...

Could someone help me to understand what is the correct one and why, please?

Comment: Just write “before”. It is shorter, more familiar and plain English. I can think of no circumstances where “prior to” is needed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Latin adjectives like prior, junior, superior, posterior, anterior etc always have preposition 'to' after them in. English. We know infinitive is a verb form with 'to' as its integral part (except bare infinitive and the few special uses). After comparatives as these with preposition'to' as their integrals, we use a gerund because of all the verb forms only a gerund(V+ing) can function as a noun. Moreover 'prior to' and 'to+ base verb' can be nonsensical.
Hence we have to use a noun or a non finite V+ing form functioning as noun.

- Prior to the introduction of...
- Prior to introducing the method of...

but not  X prior to introduce the method...X

Comment: Maybe worth noting that ***use*** in the original example would be roughly equivalent to ***the introduction*** in yours (standing for *[the] use [of the thing]*).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you're making a false analogy.

In

> prior to *use*

the word *use* is a noun, pronounced with an s-sound, not an infinitive, pronounced with a z-sound.

Thus to follow the pattern, your example would have to be

> prior to [the] introduction